# validating space in alphanumeric string thru regular expression

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I am using the following regular expression

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9 \s]{4,}"
```

to validate an alphanumeric entry with space and minimum length 4. but it doesn't accept spaces. what am i missing here.

Comment: I suspect the `nsregularexpression` tag is not valid, but I'm leaving it because the answer refers to the Apple docs, which wouldn't make sense without that tag.

Answer (score 0):

This reference over [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW48), under flag options says:

`x` `If set, allow use of white space and #comments within patterns`

It sounds like you need to set this `x` flag option for whitespace to work. If I understand it correctly, your regex should look something like

```
"(?x)[a-zA-Z0-9 \s]{4,}"
```

Comment: (/^\s*$/) I used this to validate the spaces.